# User input Zip File

Tags: python

I've recently got some user input on updating another user's code here to address an issue that I was trying to solve. It turns out the issue was in Python 2 rather than in Python 3! Here is what I have so far. When running the code I get an error:

```py
fh = open(ZipFileName, 'rb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

```py
import os
import urllib
import requests
import zipfile

r = requests.get('urlexample.zip')

with open('data.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

ZipFileName = input("Enter full path to zip file:")

fh = open(ZipFileName, 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)

DestZipFolderName = input("Assign destination folder a name:")
DestPathName = input("Enter destination directory:")
DestPathName = DestPathName + "\\" + DestZipFolderName

for name in z.namelist():
    outpath = DestPath
    z.extract(name, outpath)

fh.close()
```

Any ideas on what went wrong what be extremely helpful.

Comment: Because it has an empty string after the error, I am assuming that you just hit enter instead of providing a path to the file object (hence `No such file or directory: ''`). `ZipFileName` should be the path to a file object which is given through user input.

Comment: From @codesPliff: Did you try ```rh.zip```? Python is finicky about extensions at times.

Comment: That is an *extremely* interesting code style. Please checkout [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the standard python style guide.

Comment: SuperStormer the code style is due to me just frankenstiening code together and praying that the overall code works. I am just seriously getting into Python, but I will check out the conventions in PEP 8.

Comment: Gmdev, I do sometimes just hit the enter because I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have tried to enter a path like in an example below in my response to DapperDuck latest answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because no user input was provided. This meant that the `ZipFileName` variable was set to an empty string. So, when it was passed as a parameter into the `open()` function, there was an error. I verified this by running this part of the code:

```
import os
import urllib
import requests
import zipfile

ZipFileName = input("Enter full path to zip file:")
fh = open(ZipFileName, 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
```

I entered the path to a test zip file, and the program exited with no errors.

Comment: DapperDuck when they are suggesting entering a full path to zip file, they are suggesting for example C:\\ExampleParentDirectory\\ChildDirectory ? or something else?

Comment: Yes, a path like that, but you don't need the double backslashes.

Comment: So just to be sure it would be C: ParentDirectoryChildDirectory or C:\\ParentDirectoryChildDirectory?

Comment: C:\ParentDirectory\ChildDirectory

Comment: Ah okay, my mistake. Thank you DapperDuck you've been a great help.

Comment: No problem! If my answer worked, please mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark to the left of my answer